# Getting "Unfortunately, my-gdx-game has stopped" error using libGDX and eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I am following [this](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Video-Tutorial-Series.aspx) tutorial to learn android game programming using libGDX. Following the instructions I have been able to create a project in eclipse for both desktop and android application. My desktop application is running without any glitches. However my android application is not running on the emulator. I use API 21 to create the project and emulator. I am using java  1.7.0_79 and eclipse mars.
Each time i run the program, a "Unfortunately, my-gdx-game has stopped" error pops up. [image]

After searching through stackoverflow, I have seen the following recommendations :

1. Ensure the emulator has "use host GPU" ticked. I have done this. [image]
2. Ensure the android project properties has the same API. I have done this too.[image]

My emulator screen looks like this when running the app. There is a ? mark on the target column. Why is so? Is this causing the issue?

[image]

My logcat is showing this.

```
06-12 23:24:22.851: E/libprocessgroup(2647): failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10053: Read-only file system
06-12 23:24:22.935: E/art(2647): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
06-12 23:24:22.972: E/EGL_emulation(1125): tid 1125: eglCreateSyncKHR(1315): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647): Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 2647
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mygdx.game/com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mygdx.game-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mygdx.game-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     ... 10 more
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):         ... 14 more
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):         ... 13 more
06-12 23:24:23.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
06-12 23:24:23.370: E/ActivityManager(1492): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 384x384
06-12 23:24:45.775: E/memtrack(2674): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-12 23:24:45.775: E/android.os.Debug(2674): failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-12 23:24:46.081: E/cutils-trace(2686): Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
06-12 23:24:47.099: E/memtrack(2693): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-12 23:24:47.100: E/android.os.Debug(2693): failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-12 23:24:47.137: E/libprocessgroup(2705): failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10053: Read-only file system
06-12 23:24:47.218: E/EGL_emulation(1125): tid 1125: eglCreateSyncKHR(1315): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
06-12 23:24:47.326: E/SurfaceFlinger(1125): rejecting buffer: bufWidth=768, bufHeight=1184, front.active.{w=1, h=1}
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705): Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 2705
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mygdx.game/com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mygdx.game-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mygdx.game-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     ... 10 more
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):         ... 14 more
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):         ... 13 more
06-12 23:24:47.367: E/AndroidRuntime(2705):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
06-12 23:24:47.748: E/ActivityManager(1492): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 384x384
06-12 23:25:19.228: E/memtrack(2727): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-12 23:25:19.228: E/android.os.Debug(2727): failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-12 23:25:19.609: E/memtrack(2738): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-12 23:25:19.609: E/android.os.Debug(2738): failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-12 23:25:19.649: E/EGL_emulation(1125): tid 1125: eglCreateSyncKHR(1315): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
06-12 23:29:47.854: E/libprocessgroup(2750): failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10053: Read-only file system
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750): Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 2750
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mygdx.game/com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mygdx.game-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mygdx.game-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     ... 10 more
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):         ... 14 more
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):         ... 13 more
06-12 23:29:47.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2750):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
06-12 23:29:48.205: E/ActivityManager(1492): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 384x384
06-12 23:29:48.242: E/EGL_emulation(1125): tid 1125: eglCreateSyncKHR(1315): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

Am I missing something? Any suggestions?

Comment: Would be interesting to see at least the AndroidLauncher code.

Comment: If you can share all the code, that would be better for me to have a look at it.